# Meaning of the following code example

Tags: c++, variables, object

I need to know what the following source code means:

```
Foam::fvMesh mesh                               //object mesh of class fvMesh 
(
    Foam::IOobject                              // ?
    (
        Foam::fvMesh::defaultRegion,
        runTime.timeName(),
        runTime,
        Foam::IOobject::MUST_READ
    )
```

If I am right at the beginning there is object `mesh` of class `fvMesh` created. What does the following code in this connection mean? (starting with ? in the example)

greetings 
Streight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to me like a fairly intricate object construction.

Consider if the constructor for `fvMesh` looks something like this:

```
class fvMesh
{
  fvMesh (const IOobject& obj);
};
```

and the constructor for `IOobject` in turn looks like this:

```
class IOobject
{
  IOobject (Region, string, time, flag);
};
```

Constructing a variable named `mesh` of type `fvMesh` would be something like:

```
IOobject temp (Foam::fvMesh::defaultRegion,runTime.timeName(),runTime, Foam::IOobject::MUST_READ);

Foam::fvMesh mesh(temp);
```

But since the `fvMesh` constructor takes a const reference, you can also pass it a temporary `IOobject`, constructed on the fly and then discarded:

```
Foam::fvMesh mesh(IOobject(Foam::fvMesh::defaultRegion,runTime.timeName(),runTime, Foam::IOobject::MUST_READ));
```

This is the same as the code you've posted, except your code has some extra whitespace.

Comment: Ok, I understand that `Foam::IOobject (Region, string, time, flag)` is the constructor of class 'IOobject' and gets the arguments in the brackets. But afterwards the constructors "result" is passed to the object `Foam::fvMesh mesh` where **mesh** is the variable (object). Where do you see the fvMesh constructor?``

Comment: @Streight:  Here: `Foam::fvMesh mesh `

Comment: But the `fvMesh` constructor looks like this `Foam::fvMesh::fvMesh(const IOobject& io)`. So what is `mesh` in the code example for?

Comment: @Streight:  That's the name of the variable you're creating.

Comment: Thx for the explanation. To me this kind of defining a variable is totally new.

Comment: @Streight:  Assuming you're new to C++, what language did you come from?

Comment: I am not totally new to C++. About one and a half year ago I programmed a user interface for a specific OpenFoam Application. I read some basic C++ tutorials, but did not see or use something like the code above.

Comment: @Streight:  I see.  Although I'm no fan of the actual formatting, this kind of instantiation is quite common in my world.

Answer (score 2):

It's strangely formatted, but it's just an object initialized by calling a constructor which takes another object.

```
Type obj
(
   Type2(
     X,
     Y
   )
);
```

is

```
Type obj( Type2( X, Y ) );
```

Which means a temporary object of `Type2` is created and passed to the constructor of `Type`.